# Is there an Interactive Brokers timeline of actions?

Tags: interactive-brokers

is there an IBKR timeline of actions? I'm looking for something like (fictional timeline)

1 january: deposited $1K to account.
2 january: bought 3x brkb shares at $300/piece
3 january: bought 1x fb share at $100/piece
4 january: sold 1x brkb share at $290/piece
5 january: withdrawed $290 from account

.. can't seem to find such a timeline anywhere. i have found an account deposit+withdrawal timeline available at https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/AccountManagement/AmAuthentication?action=TransactionHistory and i have found individual stock timeline at https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/portal/#/quote/<ID> (for example brkb is ID 72063691 so i can see brkb-specific timeline at https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/portal/#/quote/72063691 and FB is ID 107113386 so i can see fb-specific timeline at https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/portal/#/quote/107113386 ), but i have not found such a timeline for all firms, just 1-firm-at-a-time..

Comment: For future reference, and for the benefit of those who currently have no Interactive Brokers account, please post a screenshot of each of the web pages in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your links are non-functional because you must be a logged in account holder to see that information.

What is a timeline?  If you mean a record of these transactions, you need to look at you daily or monthly statements.  IBKR E-mails them to you daily.  You can also download them in the Account Management section when you are logged in.

Comment: `Your links are non-functional because you must be a logged in account holder to see that information.` - makes sense, the information is account-specific after all. `What is a timeline?` - A timeline is a display of a list of events in chronological order. `IBKR E-mails them to you daily. ` - hmm maybe that is a setting or something, i certainly don't get daily emails from ibkr. i got one at 12 march, 18 march, 2 april~ maybe one every day i actually do something? haven't checked. `You can also download them in the Account Management section when you are logged in.` - excellent! but where?

Comment: when i am at https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/AccountManagement/AmAuthentication?action=UnifiedSettings i get https://i.imgur.com/oR7FNl9.png

Comment: In the bottom right under REPORTING it says STATEMENT DELIVERY.  See if that provides the option to receive statements via E-mail.  At the top it says PERFORMANCE AND REPORTS. That is where you can view/download daily, weekly, annual statements as well as tax documents.  And when in doubt, you can call IBKR customer service.